# Implement dragging an image within a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I want to implement dragging of an image within a canvas. I want simplest code for that. So far I have seen a lot of examples but they have used complex ways of implementation. I want an example that is easy to learn and implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty difficult.  You'll first need to write a function that can detect when you click a particular element.  However, before we can do that, we must define what we mean by "element".  Is it the product of a single draw instruction (e.g. a rectangle or arc), or something complex?  (Imagine I wanted to draw a cat and make the entire cat draggable as a unit.)

A canvas is nothing but a collection of pixels.  If you want your program to have an idea of "shapes" or even "collections of shapes treated as a unit" you'll need to implement them yourself as data structures external to the canvas itself.  Once you have that, you can write an `onmousedown` handler that takes the x/y point clicked and determine what shape (if any) the click falls inside of (and if it falls inside of multiple shapes, check which has the foremost z-index).  Then add an `onmousemove` handler that erases and redraws the shape on the canvas based on the information in the shape data object.

This is a moderately difficult problem with very difficult prerequisite problems (creating data structures that can describe a wide range of shapes as well as collections of shapes).  I *highly* recommend you use a canvas drawing library that has already solved these problems. I use [cake.js](http://code.google.com/p/cakejs/) but there are [loads](http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS) of [options](http://paperjs.org/) [available](http://kineticjs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to use the HTML5 canvas, jQuery UI is a lot simpler:

HTML:

```
<img class="drag-me" src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png">​
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {

    $('.drag-me').draggable();
});
```

​
See it in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/flackend/TQzSe/

The jQuery UI API has a lot of options too to make it act how you want:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Plus, if it doesn't do what you need, it's easy to implement yourself. Post here if you need help with that.

Answer (score 0):

jsfiddle.net/Zevan/QZejF/5 This may help you.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="c" width = "500" height = "500" ></canvas>


<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas = $("#c");
var c = canvas[0].getContext("2d");

//var path = "http://wonderfl.net/images/icon/e/ec/ec3c/ec3c37ba9594a7b47f1126b2561efd35df2251bfm";
var path = "blue.jpg";
var path2 = "purple.jpg";
var image1 = new DragImage(path, 200, 100);
var image2 = new DragImage(path2, 300, 100);

var loop = setInterval(function() {

    c.fillStyle = "gray";
    c.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

    image1.update();
    image2.update();
}, 30);

var mouseX = 0,
    mouseY = 0;
var mousePressed = false;
var dragging = false;
canvas.mousemove(function(e) {
    mouseX = e.offsetX;
    mouseY = e.offsetY;
})

$(document).mousedown(function() {
    mousePressed = true;
}).mouseup(function() {
    mousePressed = false;
    dragging = false;
});

function DragImage(src, x, y) {
    var that = this;
    var startX = 0,
        startY = 0;
    var drag = false;

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = src;
    this.update = function() {
        if (mousePressed ) {

                var left = that.x;
                var right = that.x + img.width;
                var top = that.y;
                var bottom = that.y + img.height;
                if (!drag) {
                    startX = mouseX - that.x;
                    startY = mouseY - that.y;
                }
                if (mouseX < right && mouseX > left && mouseY < bottom && mouseY > top) {
                    if (!dragging){
            dragging = true;
                        drag = true;
                    }

                }

        } else {

            drag = false;
        }
        if (drag) {
            that.x = mouseX - startX;
            that.y = mouseY - startY;
        }
        c.drawImage(img, that.x, that.y);
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the content of your fiddle as apart of your answer? If jsfiddle ever goes offline, the content will be lost forever.